# Multiple template engines with KeystoneJS

Tags: keystonejs

I have read all of the forums and docs I can find, but cannot find a good answer. I would like to use Jade AND EJS as template engines in KeytoneJs/Express. It seems like it is possible with express, can I do it with keystone? Any examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific use case for this? (Is there something EJS can't do that Jade can, and/or vice versa)? These two posts below might help you.

- [how to use both ejs and jade in one nodejs & express project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783413/how-to-use-both-ejs-and-jade-in-one-nodejs-express-project)
- [Is there any way to use multiple view engines with Express + Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063262/is-there-any-way-to-use-multiple-view-engines-with-express-node-js/15064438#15064438)