# Using Jade and Handlebars together and rendering accordingly

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to understand how to include jade and handlebar exactly as I am trying to add angular js to my server that is also using jade for serving other web pages.

I heard of consolidate.js and this is my app.js code:

```
var engines = require('consolidate');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

app.engine('jade', engines.jade);
app.engine('handlebars', engines.handlebars);

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'img/favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser(config.cookieSecret.secret));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

How do I get the view engine setup for both? Also, how do I add the following into my code without affecting other links:

```
 // Application UI route
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.render('indexer');
    });

app.get('/templates/*', function(req, res) {
        res.render('../client/templates/' + req.params[0])
    });
```